# publishProgress() atualiza o onProgressUpdate() somente no final do doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Tenho um app que faz a atualização da barra de progresso, da mesma forma que estou fazendo em outro app, mas nesse novo app, o `onProgressUpdate()` somente executa no final do `doInBackground()`.

É chamado o método `parseInsertSolicitantes(jsonString)`, onde no loop de inserção de registros, ele possui o `publishProgress(count)`.

Classe `Sincronizar`

```
public class Sincronizar extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sincronizar);

        this.pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBarSync);
    }

    private void syncCadastros() {

        AsyncCadastros asyncCadastros = new AsyncCadastros(this, this.pb);
        String retorno = "";

        try {
            asyncCadastros.execute();
            retorno = asyncCadastros.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("lgg", "retorno sync cad: " + retorno);
    }
}
```

Classe `AsyncCadastros`

```
public class AsyncCadastros extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    Context ctx;
    ProgressBar pb;
    ConnectivityManager conexao;

    public AsyncCadastros(Context ctx, ProgressBar pb) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.pb = pb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("lgg", "onPreExecute");
        this.pb.setProgress(0);
        this.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.i("lgg", "onPostExecute");
        this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("lgg", "onProgressUpdate: " + values[0]);
        this.pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (!verificaConexao(this.ctx)) {

            return "Sem conexão";

        } else {

               ...

                String retorno = json;

                if (retorno.equals("X")) {

                    return "X";

                } else {

                    reader.close();
                    streamReader.close();

                    String jsonString = retorno.toString();
                    parseInsertSolicitantes(jsonString);
                    return null;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean verificaConexao(Context ctx) {
        ...
    }

    private String parseInsertSolicitantes(String json) {

        String jsonString = json;

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        JSONArray jsonArray;

        int handle;
        String nome;
        DBController dbc = new DBController(ctx);

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("solicitantes");
            int count = 0;
            int regs = jsonArray.length();
            this.pb.setMax(regs);
            Log.i("lgg", "registros: " + regs);
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {

                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                handle = JO.getInt("handle");
                nome = JO.getString("nome");

                dbc.atualizarSolicitantes(handle, nome);

                Log.i("lgg", "Sync: " + count);
                count++;
                publishProgress(count);
            }

            return "parseInsertSolicitantes OK";
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "parseInsertSolicitantes ERRO";
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo da saída:

```
02-20 12:15:50.028 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onPreExecute
02-20 12:15:50.090 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: conectado 
02-20 12:15:50.363 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Solicitantes apagados
02-20 12:15:50.753 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: registros: 5
02-20 12:15:50.785 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Cadastro inserido
02-20 12:15:50.786 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Sync: 0
02-20 12:15:50.825 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Cadastro inserido
02-20 12:15:50.826 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Sync: 1
02-20 12:15:50.866 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Cadastro inserido
02-20 12:15:50.867 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Sync: 2
02-20 12:15:50.899 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Cadastro inserido
02-20 12:15:50.900 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Sync: 3
02-20 12:15:50.931 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Cadastro inserido
02-20 12:15:50.932 21648-7989/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: Sync: 4
02-20 12:15:50.943 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 12:15:50.957 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onProgressUpdate: 1
02-20 12:15:50.959 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onProgressUpdate: 2
02-20 12:15:50.960 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onProgressUpdate: 3
02-20 12:15:50.961 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onProgressUpdate: 4
02-20 12:15:50.962 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onProgressUpdate: 5
02-20 12:15:50.962 21648-21648/com.exemple.exemple I/lgg: onPostExecute
```

Um exemplo de um app que está funcionando:

```
public class JsonReceber extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    Context ctx;
    String tipoPessoa;
    ProgressBar pb;

    ConnectivityManager conexao;

    public JsonReceber(Context ctx, String tipoPessoa, ProgressBar pb) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.tipoPessoa = tipoPessoa;
        this.pb = pb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("lgg", "Inicio da sync");
        this.pb.setProgress(0);
        this.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        this.pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("lgg", "progress: " + values[0]);
        this.pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        if (!verificaConexao(this.ctx)) {

            return "Sem conexão";

        } else {

            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://");
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("lgg", "erro: " + e);
            }

            Log.i("lgg", "recebido: " + content);

            if (content.length() < 1) {
                Log.i("lgg", "content vazio");
                return "content vazio";
            } else {

                // Parse JSON e insert
                String jsonString = content.toString();
                sync(jsonString);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean verificaConexao(Context ctx) {
        this.conexao = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = this.conexao.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if ((netInfo != null) && (netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) && (netInfo.isAvailable())) {
            Log.i("lgg", "conectado");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.i("lgg", "sem conexão");
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void sync(String json) {
        String jsonString = json;
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        JSONArray jsonArray;

        int handle;
        String nome;
        DB_Controller dbc = new DB_Controller(ctx);
        if (this.tipoPessoa.equals("solicitantes"))
            dbc.apagarSolicitantes();
        else if (this.tipoPessoa.equals("clientes"))
            dbc.apagarClientes();

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(this.tipoPessoa);
            int count = 0;
            int regs = jsonArray.length();
            this.pb.setMax(regs);
            Log.i("lgg", "registros: " + regs);
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {

                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                handle = JO.getInt("handle");
                nome = JO.getString("nome");
                if (this.tipoPessoa.equals("solicitantes"))
                    dbc.atualizarSolicitantes(handle, nome);
                else if (this.tipoPessoa.equals("clientes"))
                    dbc.atualizarClientes(handle, nome);
                Log.i("lgg", "Sync: " + count);
                count++;
                publishProgress(count);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você deve chamar `onProgressUpdate` dentro do `doInBackground`

Comment: Não sabia que existia isso. Mas queria fazer como o outro, que é praticamente a mesma coisa. Coloquei na pergunta o código do que está funcionando.

Comment: O outro chama o método `publishProgress` dentro de `sync(String json)`, que por sua vez é chamado pelo `doInBackground`. Ou seja, é necessário chamar `onProgressUpdate` a partir do método `doInBackground`

Comment: O conteúdo do método `sync` estava dentro do `doInBackground`, eu só tirei para testar, como fiz no novo App. E funcionou das 2 formas. Não estou entendendo ainda o porque de por um dentro do outro...

Comment: Inclusive, os 2 chamam métodos. A única diferença é o `void`e `String` neles.

Comment: Você não está querendo dizer o `publishProgress` ao invés de `onProgressUpdate` não ?

Comment: Amigo, olhando bem seu código parece estar tudo corrento, vc diz chamar o progressUpdate no final para atualizar o seu progressBar, mas vc ja colocou um log na dentro do onProgressUpdate? Porque eu acho que tudo esta correndo tão rápido que a atualização é quase instantânea.

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa sim, o log está dentro de cada parte, é o "Exemplo de saída"... não é velocidade, porque no outro app é mais rápido ainda, inclusive eu limito para 5, 10, resultados para o teste, porque tem milhares. Eu ainda não peguei para ver novamente, mas é um mistério !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o motivo:

Na classe `Sincronizar`, o comando `retorno = asyncCadastros.get()` que bloqueia o `onProgressUpdate`.

Provavelmente porque ele espera um retorno.